# How to remove remote branch and its commit history from git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

[image]I am trying to delete the remote branch that i created for testing purpose and this command does the trick:

`git push origin --delete test`

However in my git gui I can still see the commit log message for that branch. How can i delete the commit history? There was only one commit made for this branch.

Comment: Did you mean `git push origin --delete bugs/test`?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
git branch -vva
```

to see what references you have:

```
* master                898bfa9 [origin/master] Commit A
  test                  a2b238b [origin/test] Commit B
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master 898bfa9 Commit A
  remotes/origin/test   a2b238b Commit B
```

If you see bugs/test, then to delete it:

```
git branch -d bugs/test
```

If you what you are still seeing is remotes/origin/bugs/test then [prune](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) your old remote references:

```
git remote prune origin
```